# Measure distance between the first and last location record per day and animal in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, location, distance

I have a database with >300,000 records of animal observations. Each row represents an animal location. Each animal has a unique id (`id1`) and several columns with attributes related to that animal location, including date of observation and x and y coordinates.

Could someone help me create a code that will allow me to the following:

1) Subset data by BOTH `date` and `id1`

2) Measure the distance (coordinates are in UTM so distance will be in meters) between the FIRST and LAST location record for each `date` for each different `id1`

An example of the data is the following:

```
mydata<-read.table(text = 
"id1 date x y
1 11/02/2014 478776.4332 7922167.59 
1 11/02/2014 478776.4333 7922170.59
1 11/02/2014 478776.4334 7922180.59
1 12/02/2014 478776.4335 7922190.59 
1 12/02/2014 478776.4350 7922192.59
1 12/02/2014 478776.4360 7922195.59
2 11/02/2014 478776.4338 7922167.59
2 11/02/2014 478776.4339 7922183.59
2 11/02/2014 478776.4340 7922185.59
2 12/02/2014 478776.4350 7922188.30 
2 12/02/2014 478776.4360 7922190.59
2 12/02/2014 478776.4390 7922198.59
3 11/02/2014 478776.4338 7922167.59
3 11/02/2014 478776.4345 7922175.59
3 11/02/2014 478776.4355 7922178.85
3 12/02/2014 478776.4368 7922180.59 
3 12/02/2014 478776.4398 7922183.59
3 12/02/2014 478776.4399 7922185.59
4 11/02/2014 478776.4338 7922167.59
4 11/02/2014 478776.4340 7922172.59
4 11/02/2014 478776.4345 7922178.59
3 11/02/2014 478776.4350 7922179.59
3 12/02/2014 478776.4355 7922184.59 
3 12/02/2014 478776.4360 7922187.59
3 12/02/2014 478776.4365 7922198.59",
header = TRUE)
```

A much less efficient alternative would be to select the first and last records for each `date` and `id1` and then measure distance between all pairs of points. I found a code to select the LAST record for each individual animal but I will still have to incorporate the subset by date as well:

```
myid.uni <- unique(mydata$id1)
a<-length(myid.uni)

last <- c()

for (i in 1:a) {
  temp<-subset(mydata, id1==myid.uni[i])
  if (dim(temp)[1] > 1) {
    last.temp<-temp[dim(temp)[1],]
  }
  else {
    last.temp<-temp
  }
  last<-rbind(last, last.temp)
}
```

Could someone help me with either strategy, preferentially with the most straightforward way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  group_by(id1, date) %>%
  summarize(x1 = first(x), y1 = first(y), x2 = last(x), y2 = last(y)) %>%
  mutate(distance = sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2))
```

Results:

```
Source: local data frame [7 x 7]
Groups: id1 [4]

    id1       date       x1      y1       x2      y2  distance
  (int)     (fctr)    (dbl)   (dbl)    (dbl)   (dbl)     (dbl)
1     1 11/02/2014 478776.4 7922168 478776.4 7922181 13.000000
2     1 12/02/2014 478776.4 7922191 478776.4 7922196  5.000001
3     2 11/02/2014 478776.4 7922168 478776.4 7922186 18.000000
4     2 12/02/2014 478776.4 7922188 478776.4 7922199 10.290001
5     3 11/02/2014 478776.4 7922168 478776.4 7922180 12.000000
6     3 12/02/2014 478776.4 7922181 478776.4 7922199 18.000000
7     4 11/02/2014 478776.4 7922168 478776.4 7922179 11.000000
```

Comment: It may be useful to include `arrange(id1, date)` so that the first and last really reflect first and last observations in case they are ordered differently. Also, `summarise_each(funs(first, last))` may be warranted to save some typing.

Comment: @coffeinjunky Thanks! Arranging by id1 and date won't ensure that the data is in order. After the rows are grouped by id1 and date, there is no column (say a timestamp) to order the observations. The problem as posed above assumes the observations are in the right order (after grouping on id1 and date). `summarize_each()` is a cool suggestion.

Comment: Oui, you are right! Sorry! I somehow imagined seeing a time stamp... I infer this to mean its time for me to get more coffee...

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed to do and it is just in a few lines of code!

Answer (score 5):

You can construct the data using `data.table`

```
# load data.table and make mytable a data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)

# contstruct new dataset
newData <- mydata[, .(startx=head(x, 1), endx=tail(x, 1), 
                      starty=head(y, 1), endy=tail(y, 1)),
                  by=.(id1, date)]
# calculate distance
newData[, distance := sqrt((endx-startx)^2+(endy-starty)^2)]
```

I use the same (Euclidean) distance formula as @edward-r-mazurek.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion as well lmo.